# Hidden textarea padding not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to add padding to a simple textarea .

It works perfectly if the textarea is visible on load , but if you dynamically(jQuery)
show the textarea then the padding does not take effect.

The above problem only happens in IE and **importantly** only happens before you type anything in the textarea . Once you type something the padding immediately takes effect.

Is it some IE bug or anything can be done to solve this problem ?

I have made a simple demo here :
http://loadmycode.com/build/lymj6_XFP/12

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an IE bug. If the content is not empty, like `$('textarea').val(' ').show().focus();` it displays the padding, but if you delete the space the cursor goes back to the top.

Since it works when the textarea is displayed when the page is loaded, you can use this work around: remove `display: none;` from the style and add `$('textarea').hide();` to a [`ready` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) on your page.

Demo: http://loadmycode.com/build/lymj6_XFP/29

Comment: Your idea is good, well i found another workaround by enclosing it within div tag and hiding/showing that div. Here it is: http://loadmycode.com/build/lymj6_XFP/32